# Постоянно работающий фоновый сервис

Tags: android, android-service, xamarin.android

Я пишу Android приложение, которое запускает некую длительную фоновую задачу. Я создал для этого сервис, унаследовал его от IntentService и выполняю в нём всю длительную работу. Также для того,, чтобы система не убивала этот сервис, я dspsdf. в нём метод `startForeground`. ОС его не убивает, но как бы замораживает. Если выйти из приложения, но продолжать пользоваться телефоном, то сервис продолжает работать в фоне. Но если погасить экран телефона, то работа сервиса почти сразу же приостанавливается. Если снова включить экран, то сервис возобновляет работу. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой и знает, как её решить?

Comment: Попробуйте протетстировать еще на нескольких устройствах. Работа сервисов в бэкграунде у разных моделей смартфонов и на разных прошивках отличается, например, у Xiaomi

Comment: @Valgaal у меня именно Xiaomi. А может быть есть какие-то средства, позволяющие заставить это работать и для Xiaomi? Другие приложения (в частности торрент-клиенты) работают в фоне без остановок в том числе и на моём устройстве

Comment: Я сейчас прочитал вопрос еще раз и я так понял он заключается в том, что вы хотите, чтобы сервис работал, когда экран выключен. Тогда вам нужен WakeLock. Вы его должны получать, когда начинаете работу и делать release, когда заканчиваете